# Can't set file descriptor to blocking mode

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, termios

I am tring to write the shortest code to have a blocking file descriptor.

I set first: O_NONBLOCK
second: ICANON, [VMIN], [VTIME] for my file descriptor...

What else options I need to set to have a blocking file descriptor ?

(sample.txt is empty & open() with different mode does not chance anything)

---

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>


void set_blocking(int fd, int blocking) {

    int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);

    if (blocking)
        flags &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
    else
        flags |= O_NONBLOCK;

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);

    return;
}

int main(){

        int fd;
        char buff[100];
        struct termios options;

        options.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;

        options.c_cc[VMIN] = 2;
        options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

        fd = open("sample.txt",O_RDWR);

        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

        set_blocking(fd,1);

        read(fd,buff,2);

        printf("%s\n",buff);

        return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Recommend using `fcntl()` to get and save the original terminal settings so you can restore them before exiting.  And modify those rather than setting them from scratch.

Comment: `tcsetattr` only works on special terminal device files, not on ordinary files. I doubt that your "sample.txt" is a terminal.

Comment: You do not check for error returns of any system call. If you want to know why system calls fail to work as expected, you must diagnose error returns. At a minimum, use `perror` to show the error reason. Please do this *before* posting here.

Comment: After I delete codes about terminos and terminos options, (because as i understand, i don't need them) code still do not wait for empty sample.txt which is ordinary text file.
I would appreciate if i had a minimalist sample code which has a waiting read function when called for a ordinary text file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is modifying only parts of an uninitialized `struct termios options` variable. When your code calls `tcsetattr`, most of the `options` variable will be set to random bits, so `tcsetattr` is likely to either return an error or apply bogus settings to the terminal.

Since your code only modifies certain terminal settings explicitly, the best way to initialize the `options` variable would be to read the old settings into it using a call to `tcgetattr`:

```
    ret = tcgetattr(fd, &options);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("tcgetattr");
        exit(1);
    }

    options.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;

    options.c_cc[VMIN] = 2;
    options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    ret = tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("tcsetattr");
        exit(1);
    }
```

The code sample above assumes that the file descriptor `fd` is linked to a terminal, so that `isatty(fd)` returns 1. It does not apply at all when `fd` is linked to an ordinary file.

In your posted code, `fd` is linked to a file called "sample.txt" in the current directory, which is unlikely to be a terminal.  In that case, the `tcgetattr` and `tcsetattr` calls will return `-1` and set `errno` to `ENOTTY`.